# How to sum all rows when using filter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables

I have been reading many jQuery Datatables examples on how to use `footerCallback` to sum all rows of a MySQL table, but I can get the total sum of a column, when I'm using records per page filter. In the [Footer callback example](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html), they show a demo, that do that, here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
            var api = this.api(), data;

            // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
            var intVal = function ( i ) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
            };

            // Total over all pages
            data = api.column( 4 ).data();
            total = data.length ?
                data.reduce( function (a, b) {
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                } ) :
                0;

            // Total over this page
            data = api.column( 4, { page: 'current'} ).data();
            pageTotal = data.length ?
                data.reduce( function (a, b) {
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                } ) :
                0;

            // Update footer
            $( api.column( 4 ).footer() ).html(
                '$'+pageTotal +' ( $'+ total +' total)'
            );
        }
    } );
} );
```

But when I apply in my PHP script, total gives me the same amount of pageTotal, when My records per page filter is on 10, if I change to 50 it gives me a new total, but how in the example, when the filter is on 10, it show the sum of all records in the table. I have been on this for two days, can anybody can give me a hint please?

Comment: are `total` and `pageTotal` different values?

Comment: No, allways are the same, but in the example are different -> http://www.abagraf.com.br/wp-content/config/DataTables/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html

Comment: so what does `apply in my php script` mean?

Comment: Please post your actual DataTables initialization code, because the examples that you're mentioning work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Total over this page

```
    data = api.column( 4, {filter:'applied'} ).data();
    pageTotal = data.length ?
        data.reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
        } ) :
        0;
```